# Is Promise.all not working on the second time through? Why not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, promise

I'm just finishing off this basic webscraper project for a tshirt website.

It enters through one hardcoded url, the home page. It will search for any product pages, and add them to an url. If it finds another link (`remainder`), it will scrape that again and find any more product pages. It adds the product pages to `urlSet` and will then scrape those again, grab the tshirt data (price, img, title) and then convert, then write them to a CSV file.

For some reason, this is not working on the second run through of the scrape with 'remainder'.

If I remove the second scrape of url, everything works out fine and the file gets written correctly. But if I want to get the other product pages, it seems to be failing somewhere.

Here is my code, i apologise for posting so much of it but I don't know how it will be understood properly without the right context, hopefully it's been commented okay:

```
//TASK: Create a command line application that goes to an ecommerce site to get the latest prices.
    //Save the scraped data in a spreadsheet (CSV format).

'use strict';

//Modules being used:
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var request = require('request');
var moment = require('moment');
var fs = require('fs');

//harcoded url
var url = 'http://shirts4mike.com/';

//url for tshirt pages
var urlSet = new Set();

var remainder;
var tshirtArray = [];


const requestPromise = function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(error, response, html) {

            if(error)return reject(error);

            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                return resolve(html);   
            }       
        });
    });
}


// Go into webpage via url, load html and grab links shirt in url
function scrape (url) {
    console.log("Currently scraping " + url)
    return requestPromise(url)
        .then(function(html) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            var links = [];

            //get all the links
            $('a[href*=shirt]').each(function(){
                var a = $(this).attr('href');
                //add into link array
                links.push(url + a);
            });
            // return array of links
            return links;
        });
}


function nextStep (arrayOfLinks) { 
    var promiseArray = [];
    console.log(arrayOfLinks);
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfLinks.length; i++){
        promiseArray.push(requestPromise(arrayOfLinks[i]));
    }
    //return both the html of pages and their urls
    return Promise.all(promiseArray)
        .then(function(arrayOfHtml){
        return {arrayOfHtml: arrayOfHtml , arrayOfUrls: arrayOfLinks};
    });                 
}


//go through the html of each url and add to urlSet if there is a checkout button
//add to remainder otherwise to rescrape
function lastStep (obj){ 
    for(var i = 0;  i < obj.arrayOfHtml.length; i++){
        var $ = cheerio.load(obj.arrayOfHtml[i]);

        //if page has a submit it must be a product page
        if($('[type=submit]').length !== 0){

            //add page to set
            urlSet.add(obj.arrayOfUrls[i]);
            console.log(obj.arrayOfUrls[i]);

        } else if(remainder == undefined) {
            //if not a product page, add it to remainder so it another scrape can be performed.
            remainder = obj.arrayOfUrls[i];
            console.log("The remainder is " + remainder)                                     
        }
    }
    //return remainder for second run-through of scrape 
    return remainder;
}


//iterate through urlSet (product pages and grab html)
function lastScraperPt1(){
    //call lastScraper so we can grab data from the set (product pages)
        //scrape set, product pages
        var promiseArray = [];

        for(var item of urlSet){
            var url = item;

            promiseArray.push(requestPromise(url));
        }
        return Promise.all(promiseArray)
            .then(function(arrayOfHtml){
                return arrayOfHtml;
            });    
}


//iterate over the html of the product pages and store data as objects
function lastScraperPt2(html){
    for(var i = 0; i < html.length; i++){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html[i]);

        //grab data and store as variables
        var price = $('.price').text();
        var imgURL = $('.shirt-picture').find('img').attr('src');
        var title = $('body').find('.shirt-details > h1').text().slice(4);

        var tshirtObject = {};
        //add values into tshirt object
        tshirtObject.Title = title;
        tshirtObject.Price = price;
        tshirtObject.ImageURL = imgURL;
        tshirtObject.URL = url;
        tshirtObject.Date = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');

        //add the object into the array of tshirts
        tshirtArray.push(tshirtObject);
    }
    convertJson2Csv();
}


//convert tshirt objects and save as CSV file
function convertJson2Csv(){
        //The scraper should generate a folder called `data` if it doesn’t exist.
        var dir ='./data';
        if(!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }

        var fields = ['Title', 'Price', 'ImageURL', 'URL', 'Date'];

        //convert tshirt data into CSV and pass in fields
        var csv = json2csv({ data: tshirtArray, fields: fields });

        //Name of file will be the date
        var fileDate = moment().format('MM-DD-YY');
        var fileName = dir + '/' + fileDate + '.csv';

        //Write file
        fs.writeFile(fileName, csv, {overwrite: true}, function(err) {
            console.log('file saved');
            if (err) throw err;
        });
}

scrape(url) //scrape from original entry point
    .then(nextStep) 
    .then(lastStep)
    .then(scrape) //scrape again but with remainder url
    .then(nextStep)
    .then(lastStep)
    .then(lastScraperPt1)
    .then(lastScraperPt2)
    .catch(function(err) {
        // handle any error from any request here
        console.log(err);
     });
```

I'm console logging the `arrayOfLinks` in `nextStep` so I can see that they are being grabbed properly, I just cannot work out why they aren't being passed through to 'lastStep' properly.

```
Currently scraping http://shirts4mike.com/
[ 'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.php',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.php',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=108',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=107',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=106',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=105' ]
The remainder is http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.php
http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=108
http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=107
http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=106
http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=105
Currently scraping http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.php
[ 'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.phpshirts.php',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.phpshirt.php?id=101',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.phpshirt.php?id=102',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.phpshirt.php?id=103',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.phpshirt.php?id=104',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.phpshirt.php?id=105',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.phpshirt.php?id=106',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.phpshirt.php?id=107',
  'http://shirts4mike.com/shirts.phpshirt.php?id=108' ]
```

BUT if I choose to only call the first scrape and don't call the second, like this:

```
scrape(url) //scrape from original entry point
    .then(nextStep) 
    .then(lastStep)
    .then(lastScraperPt1)
    .then(lastScraperPt2)
    .catch(function(err) {
        // handle any error from any request here
        console.log(err);
     });
```

... Then everything works. I just don't get to all the urls.

What is happening here and how can I fix it? Thank you guys

Comment: How are the functions called? Are there any errors logged at `console`?

Comment: oops, sorry, added the function calls. and no errors logged

Comment: Why is `convertJson2Csv();` not returned from `lastScraperPt2`?

Comment: why does it need to be returned? it's called

Comment: `convertJson2Csv` is called without passing `tshirtArray` from within `lastScraperPt2`; `tshirtArray` does not appear to be defined within `convertJson2Csv`?

Comment: since `convertJson2Csv()` is being called at the end of the last function in the promise chain, it doesn't make a huge difference if nothing is returned. If there were an additional function in the promise chain after `lastScraperPt2`, it would just be passed `undefined`. A note regarding your code style: using `2` in place of `to` in your function name is probably not a wise choice.

Comment: tshirtArray is a global variable though so I don't know why that would make a difference. If I skip the second scrape through, everything works fine so I don't think it's that.

Thanks for the tip on style, I'll fix that for sure.

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: When you say 'add it to remainder' in your comment, that sounds like remainder should be an array?

Comment: commented in your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `tshirtArray` is not defined in `convertJson2Csv()`. At `lastlastScraperPt2` pass `tshirtArray` to `convertJsonCsv()`

```
convertJson2Csv(tshirtArray)
```

at `convertJson2Csv`

```
function convertJson2Csv(tshirtArray) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: tshirtArray is a global variable though, i don't think that'll make a difference

Comment: Ok. Did not initially notice that. Does `var $ = cheerio.load(obj.arrayOfHtml[i]);` return result asynchronously?

Comment: cheerio is not asynchronous.

Comment: Difficult to determine. Can you try to reproduce the issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: does that work for node? how could it test the csv writing?

Comment: The important portion to reproduce would be the flow of processes. You can substitute any return value having similar data structure

Comment: okay here it is in jsfiddle. I'm not sure how to get the 3rd party modules to work :s: https://jsfiddle.net/u63f3ztm/

Comment: That is a start. Not sure if `require` portion can be used at jsfiddle without `browserify`. You can load external libraries or resources by clicking "JAVASCRIPT" or "External Resources" at lest panel. Also, since `html` elements are referenced in `javascript`, it would probably help to include `html` at top left panel

Comment: damn, it doesn't seem to have the ones this program needs

Answer (score 1):

One problem seems to be in your `lastStep`. It looks like you mean for `remainder` to be another array of urls. Correct me if I'm wrong there. However, what's happing is that the first time the `if($('[type=submit]').length !== 0)` condition fails, you'll automatically go down to the next block, because `remainder` start undefined. Whatever the current url is, you assign that one to `remainder`. For the rest of the iterations of your for-loop, you will never again hit the condition where `remainder == undefined`. So if you will only ever end up with one url assigned to `remainder`, while any more that you were hoping to get will simply be passed over.

You might want to define `remainder` as `remainder = [];`. And then instead of saying `else if (remainder == undefined)`, you would just say

```
} else {
    remainder.push(obj.arrayOfUrls[i]);
}
```

However, then you're passing an array of urls to `scrape` when `scrape` is only expecting a single url. If this is what you want and I am right in assuming that you mean for `remainder` to be an array of urls, you could defined a new function as follows:

```
function scrapeRemainders(remainders) {
  var promises = [];

  remainder.forEach(function (url) {
    promises.push(requestPromise(url));
  });

  return Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
    _.flattenDeep(results);
  })
}
```

Then instead of the second `scrape` in your promise chain, you would replace it with `scrapeRemainders`. Also, for you the `_` in the previous function, you would need to `npm install lodash` and then `var _ = require('lodash')`. On a side note, lodash has nothing to do with promises, but it is a great tool for data manipulation. You should look into it when you have the chance.

Also, in `lastScraperPt1`, you can change

```
return Promise.all(promiseArray)
    .then(function(arrayOfHtml){
        return arrayOfHtml;
    });
```

to

```
return Promise.all(promiseArray);
```

It does the same thing.

Hope this helps. If this does not answer your question, comment at me and I can change my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't think so dude, I return `remainder` at the end of lastStep. Please see above, in my console that I log the url currently being scraped.

Comment: yeah you're right. changed my answer. what is remainder supposed to be? What are you expecting it to contain?

Comment: Sorry Hayden, I should have been more clear in my original question. Remainder should be just ONE url. 

The website I'm scraping is http://shirts4mike.com which is the first entry point. I search the link urls for 'shirt'. I then make another request onto those pages, one by one, and if there is a submit button (for checkout) then I know to add it to `urlSet`. Those urls are like this: `http://www.shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=107`

Comment: however, there is ALSO on the main page, this link: `http://www.shirts4mike.com/shirt.php`. This is actually a link to the full menu of tshirts. Because it doesn't have a submit button, then I know it's not a submit page so it's not a product page. So this URL becomes `remainder` so I can perform another deeper scrape to look for product pages. Does that make sense?

Comment: The reason I check that remainder is NOT undefined is because I don't want to be performing needless scrapes on the same page (because there's more than one of the same link on the homepage). I already know there'll be just one tshirt menu, yet I can only hardcode the homepage. I guess this is a pretty brittle solution but this is just a small project for my first time working with node.

Comment: What do you think, Hayden?

Comment: I see this is an exercise you're doing for tree house. So you're saying that after the initial round of scraping, you want to go back and scrape `http://www.shirts4mike.com/shirt.php`. And you're saying that you always know that this is the url you want to scrape, but the exercise has specified that you are not allowed to hard code it? I looked at the webpage and saw that the link appears more than once so I think I get your context now.

Comment: It's okay, I fixed it and answered my own question, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

All fixed, it was grabbing the wrong urls in `scrape()`. Though I only knew this after I logged the statusCodes to the console :

```
//TASK: Create a command line application that goes to an ecommerce site to get the latest prices.
    //Save the scraped data in a spreadsheet (CSV format).

'use strict';

//Modules being used:
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var request = require('request');
var moment = require('moment');
var fs = require('fs');

//harcoded url
var urlHome = 'http://shirts4mike.com/';

//url for tshirt pages
var urlSet = [];

var tshirtArray = [];


const requestPromise = function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(error, response, html) {

            if(error) { 
                errorHandler(error);
                return reject(error);
            }

            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                return resolve(html);   
            }

            if(response.statusCode !== 200){
                console.log("response code is " + response.statusCode);
            }

            return resolve("");      
        });
    });
}


// Go into webpage via url, load html and grab links shirt in url
function scrape (url) {
    console.log("Currently scraping " + url)
    return requestPromise(url)
        .then(function(html) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            var links = [];
            var URL = 'http://shirts4mike.com/';
            //get all the links
            $('a[href*=shirt]').each(function(){
                var a = $(this).attr('href');
                //add into link array
                links.push(URL + a);
            });
            // return array of links
            return links;
        });
}




function nextStep (arrayOfLinks) { 
    var promiseArray = [];
    console.log(arrayOfLinks);
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfLinks.length; i++){
        promiseArray.push(requestPromise(arrayOfLinks[i]));
    }
    //return both the html of pages and their urls
    return Promise.all(promiseArray)
        .then(function(arrayOfHtml){
        return {arrayOfHtml: arrayOfHtml , arrayOfUrls: arrayOfLinks};
    });                 
}


//go through the html of each url and add to urlSet if there is a checkout button
//add to remainder otherwise to rescrape
function lastStep (obj){ 
    for(var i = 0;  i < obj.arrayOfHtml.length; i++){
        var $ = cheerio.load(obj.arrayOfHtml[i]);

        //if page has a submit it must be a product page
        if($('[type=submit]').length !== 0){

            //add page to set
            urlSet.push(obj.arrayOfUrls[i]);
            console.log(obj.arrayOfUrls[i]);

        } else if(remainder == undefined) {
            //if not a product page, add it to remainder so it another scrape can be performed.
            var remainder = obj.arrayOfUrls[i];
            console.log("The remainder is " + remainder)                                     
        }
    }
    //return remainder for second run-through of scrape 
    return remainder;
}


//iterate through urlSet (product pages and grab html)
function lastScraperPt1(){
    //call lastScraper so we can grab data from the set (product pages)
        //scrape set, product pages
        var promiseArray = [];

        for(var item of urlSet){
            var url = item;

            promiseArray.push(requestPromise(url));
        }
        return Promise.all(promiseArray)
            .then(function(arrayOfHtml){
                return arrayOfHtml;
            });    
}


//iterate over the html of the product pages and store data as objects
function lastScraperPt2(html){
    for(var i = 0; i < html.length; i++){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html[i]);

        //grab data and store as variables
        var price = $('.price').text();
        var imgURL = $('.shirt-picture').find('img').attr('src');
        var title = $('body').find('.shirt-details > h1').text().slice(4);

        var tshirtObject = {};
        //add values into tshirt object
        tshirtObject.Title = title;
        tshirtObject.Price = price;
        tshirtObject.ImageURL = urlHome + imgURL;
        tshirtObject.URL = urlSet[i];
        tshirtObject.Date = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');

        //add the object into the array of tshirts
        tshirtArray.push(tshirtObject);
    }
    return tshirtArray;
}


//conver tshirt objects and save as CSV file
function convertJson2Csv(tshirtArray){
        //The scraper should generate a folder called `data` if it doesn’t exist.
        var dir ='./data';
        if(!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }

        var fields = ['Title', 'Price', 'ImageURL', 'URL', 'Date'];

        //convert tshirt data into CSV and pass in fields
        var csv = json2csv({ data: tshirtArray, fields: fields });

        //Name of file will be the date
        var fileDate = moment().format('MM-DD-YY');
        var fileName = dir + '/' + fileDate + '.csv';

        //Write file
        fs.writeFile(fileName, csv, {overwrite: true}, function(err) {
            console.log('file saved');
            if (err) errorHandler(err);
        });
}


scrape(urlHome) //scrape from original entry point
    .then(nextStep) 
    .then(lastStep)
    .then(scrape)
    .then(nextStep)
    .then(lastStep)
    .then(lastScraperPt1)
    .then(lastScraperPt2)
    .then(convertJson2Csv)
    .catch(function(err) {
        // handle any error from any request here
        console.log(err);
     });


//If the site is down, an error message describing the issue should appear in the console. 
    //This is to be tested by disabling wifi on your device.
    //When an error occurs log it to a file scraper-error.log . It should append to the bottom of the file with a time stamp and error

var errorHandler = function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log('The scraper could not not scrape data from ' + url + ' there is either a problem with your internet connection or the site may be down');
    /**
    * create new date for log file
     */
    var loggerDate = new Date();
    /**
     * create message as a variable
    */
    var errLog = '[' + loggerDate + '] ' + error.message + '\n';
    /**
    *when the error occurs, log that to the error logger file
    */
    fs.appendFile('scraper-error.log', errLog, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('There was an error. The error was logged to scraper-error.log');
    });
};
```

Comment: Awesome, make sure to accept your answer so that others know the question is resolved. Glad you were able to figure it out. One final note on your code style: If you wanted to, you could simplify the logic of your program a bit. Instead of going through `scrape`, `nextStep`, `lastStep` twice, you could just get all the t-shirt urls from the first page, add those to your array of urls, then get all the other t-shirt urls from the next page and and those to the array only if they do not already exist. Then you could go through all of your urls at the same time to get the prices.

Comment: I know from experience that simplifying logic makes the code more readable. Because at some point you might want to come back to this code, and if it's any longer than a week later, you'll probably forget what you were doing. Making the code more readable helps you remember more easily what you were doing. Best of luck as you're learning to use node and javascript!

Comment: Thank you, Hayden!